# How to change column unit?

Tags: r

```
Fish nums   Weight(KG)
ALB   65     11000
BET   70     20000
YFT   64     11500
```

How do I change the Weight unit into "Tone"?
as below

```
Fish nums   Weight(Tone)
ALB   65     11
BET   70     20
YFT   64     11.5
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you even attempt to research elsewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Basic research is strongly encouraged before you post a question. Please make an attempt to solve the problem on your own before you ask a question, and please also include your research efforts so far.

Comment: Try to search for an answer, this is a straightforward task involving a simple indexing and division, find the logic to this chunk of code `dat <- transform(dat,  Weight(KG)= Weight(KG)/1000)` and then rename
`colnames(dat)[3] <- "Weight(Tone)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better not to put parentheses into column names. But the answer to your question is straight forward (like already mentioned)

```
temp <- read.table(text = "Fish nums   Weight.KG
ALB   65     11000
BET   70     20000
YFT   64     11500", header = T) # your data set

temp["Weight.KG"] <- temp["Weight.KG"]/1000
colnames(temp)[match("Weight.KG",colnames(temp))] <- "Weight.Tone"
```

Comment: For the other English speaking regions the word brackets generally means `[`,`]` or `<`,`>` pairs and `(` and `)` are called parentheses. I was a bit surprised to discover the Great British usage since PAM Dirac (one of GB's greatest physicists) had introduce the bra `<x|` and the ket `|x>` as names for matrix operators way back at the dawn of quantum mechanics 90 years ago.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat - in my experience down here in Oz `(` and `)` are commonly referred to as 'brackets' as well as 'parentheses.'

Comment: I imagine that GB and Oz have better claims to "ownership" of R terminology than hte US, so I'm only pointing out a difference in the experience of various users.